# php button that writes a form field entry to file

Tags: php

I have a search form where someone enters a word, and a match is found (or not found) in the database.  If there are no results, I want to display a button that just says "suggest it".  They don't enter anything - just click the button, and the word they searched for gets written to a txt file so I can review it later.

Is this correct?

```
<?php
$term = mysql_real_escape_string(sanitizeString($_POST['term']));
//other code for when result is found.
//if no result found:
<form name="suggestit" action="" method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" name="tb1" default="<?php echo $term; ?>" /><p>
    <input type="button" class="styled-button-11" id="bt1" value="Suggest It!" /></p>
</form>

if (isset($_POST['tb1'])) {
    echo writetermstofile();
    return;
}
function writetermstofile () {
$fp = fopen('suggestedterms.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $term\n);
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

I added \n after $term in $fwrite because I want each successive term that gets written (everytime clicks the button) to go on a new line.

Comment: use `$fp = fopen('suggestedterms.txt', 'a+');` to append the text to file

Comment: not valid code above

Comment: action is missing the closing parentheses and the, well, action.

Comment: that and the opening `<?php` is kind of important

Comment: fixed action="" and added the php opening and closing tags.

Comment: Why not just add it to the db with an approve flag?

Comment: You can't have a form action like that. Acton points to a page not a function

Comment: OK.  Thanks for the comments.  I changed it to: 
if (isset($_POST['bt1'])) {
    $file = fopen('suggestedterms.txt', 'a+');
    fwrite($file, $term);
    fclose($file); and I added method="post" to the form tag.
         }
However it's still not writing anything to the file.  (text file is chmodded to 777).

Comment: I've posted an answer for you below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were a few things wrong with your code.

`type="button"` should be `type="submit"` and naming the submit button, while adding to the conditional statement, *it's best*.

`$term\n` should be  `. "\n"` concatenating the `\n`

You also had a missing closing `?>` for your first `<?php` tag, then a missing `<?php` below the form. You can't inject HTML into PHP like that.

You then need to pass `$term` into your function.

Now, I don't know what `sanitizeString()` does, so if that's already working for you, great. If not, I can't help you with that.

The following works and tested using `$term ="The term";` in place of what you're already using (which am under the impression your query already works), and seeing I couldn't test it with a DB.

Sidenotes: As stated in comments, to append to a file, use the `a` or `a+` switch. Using the `w` switch, overwrites any previous content.

```
$fp = fopen('suggestedterms.txt', 'a+');
```

FYI: `name="suggestit"` forms don't have names. It's in my code below, but you can safely delete it.

You're also going to need to use a name attribute in your form to go along with `$_POST['term']`, since there isn't one named `name="term"`. You may have meant to use `$_POST['tb1']`.

If that isn't the case, then I'm assuming you will want to use an input for the search term itself:
`<input type="text" name="term">`, so just add it to your form **if** that's what you want to achieve.

**Code:**

```
<?php
$term = mysql_real_escape_string(sanitizeString($_POST['term']));

//other code for when result is found.
//if no result found:

?>

<form name="suggestit" action="" method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" name="tb1" default="<?php echo $term; ?>" /><p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="styled-button-11" id="bt1" value="Suggest It!" /></p>
</form>

<?php

 if (isset($_POST['tb1']) && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo writetermstofile($term);
    return;
}
function writetermstofile ($term) {


$fp = fopen('suggestedterms.txt', 'w'); // to append use 'a' or 'a+'
fwrite($fp, $term . "\n");
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

Footnotes:

As per a comment you wrote *"text file is chmodded to 777"*.

Text files should be chmod'ed to 644, rather than 777. It's safer.

Answer (score 1):

> However it's still not writing anything to the file.

Sure, because you write in the file the variable `$term` which is in your case is:

```
$term = mysql_real_escape_string(sanitizeString($_POST['term']));
```

But the $_POST['term'] is not defined in your form context.
Probably the first input you need to write this way to have $_POST['term'] sent by browser:

```
<input type="hidden" name="term" value="<?php echo $term; ?>" />
```

and sure the second `input` tag should be with the `type='submit'`